# Mathematica - set end-of-line characters when importing

Tags: import

I have a plain text file of tab-separated values that was created on a Windows machine. I want to import it into Mathematica on a Mac.

```
rawdata = Import["filename.csv", "tsv"]
```

The output list has a blank list every other element. I think this is due to the old `\r\n`-vs-`\n` compatibility issue. How can I tell `Import` which convention the input file is using?

Edit: I should mention that I want to do this in a cross-platform way, because I'll probably be moving notebooks between Mac and Windows machines. So simply skipping every other element of the output list (`[[1;2;-1]]`) won't work.

Edit 2: This is what the file looks like when I open it in Emacs:

```
...
4.510000000000000E+008  -1.052316667849458E+002 -1.412043034275902E+002 ^M
4.515000000000000E+008  -1.159523802353636E+002 1.631532615796773E+002 ^M
...
```

The spaces between the fields are tabs. A moment's Googling tells me that `^M` is a carriage return (`\r`). This fits my hypothesis that the Windows-based device is terminating lines with `\r\n`, and Mathematica is reading that as two new-lines. My question remains: How do I tell `Import` what EOL characters are in use in my file?

Comment: Why the file name extension is `.csv` while the format of the file is `TSV`? The `Import` must not depend on this but it is strange. Which *Mathematica* version are you using?

Comment: @belisarius I did. @AlexeyPopkov it was generated by a scientific instrument, and that's the format it came in. `csv` files are just plain text anyway.

Comment: @poorsod - check the HEX of the end-of-line with an editor like Vim.  Regular CSV end-of-line should be OdOa (as in CR/LF or \r\n).  Perhaps you have something else.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen, please see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that "IgnoreEmptyLines" might do the trick:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you! This cleared it right up.