# When exporting text, how can I set the line separator?

Tags: export, text, linux, windows

I want to export a string for a bash script. The terminal is naturally very picky when it comes down to the "\n\r" vs "\n", Windows vs. Linux, new line issue.

How can I teach *Mathematica* to use "\n" rather than "\n\r" as the line separator when exporting text (in Windows)?

I found a couple of posts regards the same issue, but they were concerned with importing files. For example, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17954/mathematica-set-end-of-line-characters-when-importing). None of the suggested solutions worked for my case.

I played with `CharacterEncoding` and `"LineSeparators"` but nothing worked.

EDIT:
Great thanks to Mark Adler for giving me the right clue.
His suggested solution `WriteString[f, "\n"]` did not work because "\n" is interpreted by *Mathematica* as string not as end-of-line.

However, his suggested `DOSTextFormat -> False` option also works as option for `Export[]`.

I got the desired result using `Export[filename,script,"Text",DOSTextFormat -> False]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great thanks to Mark Adler for giving me the right clue. His suggested solution `WriteString[f, "\n"]` did not work because `"\n"` is interpreted by *Mathematica* as string not as end-of-line.

However, his suggested `DOSTextFormat -> False` option also works as option for `Export[]`.

I got the desired result using `Export[filename,script,"Text",DOSTextFormat -> False]`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `WriteString[]` which does not append a new line, and then write the new line character yourself.  E.g. `WriteString[f, "\n"]`.

Also you can try `DOSTextFormat -> False` as an `OpenWrite[]` option.  I don't have a Windows system to try it out on.

Answer (score 3):

This did not work for me because I wanted to create a Windows CSV file from a Macintosh.  I tried `DOSTextFormat->True` but it did nothing.  I found that you have the most control using the `"Table"` format because you can set the field and line separators.  For CSV windows files:

```
Export[fileToWrite, avgdata, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> ",", "LineSeparators" -> "\r\n"]
```

For CSV Mac/Unix files:

```
Export[fileToWrite, avgdata, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> ",", "LineSeparators" -> "\n"]
```